# ggplot and bars' color: is it possible to change the color of a specific bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, bar-chart

I'm working with ggplot and I'm trying to make a bar plot. Is there a way to change the color of a specific bar inside the plot, leaving all the others unchanged? I'm using this script:

```
  ggplot(aes(fill=name, x= `City Name`, y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", width = 0.7)+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100, 5))+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(format(pcty),"%"), y = pcty), hjust= 0, vjust= 1.5, size = 3.5, colour = "black")+
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
      axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
      axis.title.y = element_blank(),
      axis.text = element_text(face="bold"))
```

It gives me this plot, which is ok

[image: BAR PLOT]

Is there a way to have the color of the bars of the city "Savona" in red and blue (rather than pink and lightblue) and leave all the other the same???

Comment: If you could be able to provide a reproducible code, that would be great to answer your question for others. Otherwise, it is very hard to rerun the code and see what can be done to respond to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mapping `fill` to `name`, map `fill` to the `interaction` between `name` and `City Name`. Then supply a vector of fill colors using `scale_fill_manual` - these can be whatever you want:

```r
ggplot(aes(fill = interaction(name, `City Name`), x = `City Name`, y = value)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity", width = 0.7)+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,100, 5))+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(format(pcty),"%"), y = pcty), 
            hjust= 0, vjust= 1.5, size = 3.5, 
            colour = rep(c(rep("black", 3), 'white'), each = 2)) +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(rep(c('#f8766d', '#00bfc4'), 3), 
                               'red3', 'blue4')) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(face="bold"))
```

[image]

---

**Data used (inferred from plot)**

```r
data.frame(name = rep(c('A', 'B'), 4),
           `City Name` = rep(c('Genova', 'Imperia', 'La Spezia', 'Savona'),
                             each = 2),
           value = c(52, 47.77, 43, 56.85, 49, 50.33, 52, 47.10),
           pcty = c(47.77, 47.77, 56.85, 56.85, 50.33, 50.33, 47.10, 47.10),
           check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: I'm trying to replicate your code for another group of cities (they are 10 now) changing the subset, but R replies `Error in `palette()`:
! Insufficient values in manual scale. 18 needed but only 8 provided.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.` How can I solve?

Comment: The `values` in `scale_fill_manual` are a vector of colours that are passed to the bars in the order they appear. In my example this is `c(rep(c('#f8766d', '#00bfc4'), 3),  'red3', 'blue4')`, which means "repeat pink and pale blue three times, then dark red, then dark blue". I don't know which city you want to highlight. If it is the last one, you would do  `c(rep(c('#f8766d', '#00bfc4'), 8),  'red3', 'blue4')` because you need 8 pairs of pink/pale blue. If you want the third one highlighted it would be `c(rep(c('#f8766d', '#00bfc4'), 2),  'red3', 'blue4', rep(c('#f8766d', '#00bfc4'), 6))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @AllanCameron ! In this case i have 9 cities and i want to change the color the eighth. I've added `  scale_fill_manual(values = c(rep(c('#f8766d', '#00bfc4'), 7), '#FF3333', '#3399FF',  '#f8766d', '#00bfc4'))  ` , but R replies <<Error in `geom_text()`:
! Problem while setting up geom aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (18)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `colour`
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.>>

Comment: @io_boh. Remove the `colour = rep(c(rep("black", 3), 'white'), each = 2)` from inside `geom_text` and it will work fine.